# Get part of string using php

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, preg-match

How to get a part of string using PHP?

I have a string like this.

```
$str = 'href="http://www.idontknow.com/areyousure?answer=yes"';
```

I want only the link.. like this

```
$str_new = "http://www.idontknow.com/areyousure?answer=yes";
```

Comment: What kind of strings you expect to get in $str? Maybe substr() won't help and you'll need to use REGEXP.

Answer (score 5):

```
$str_new = substr($str, 6, -1);
```

[`substr()`](http://php.net/function.substr)

> If length is given and is positive, the string returned will contain at most length characters beginning from start (depending on the length of string).
>
> **If length is given and is negative, then that many characters will be omitted from the end of string (after the start position has been calculated when a start is negative).** If start denotes the position of this truncation or beyond, false will be returned.
>
> If length is given and is 0, FALSE or NULL an empty string will be returned.
>
> If length is omitted, the substring starting from start until the end of the string will be returned.

Answer (score 4):

```
$str = 'href="http://www.idontknow.com/areyousure?answer=yes"';
preg_match('/href="(.*)"/', $str, $matches);
$str_new = $matches[1];

echo $str_new;
```

Output:

```
http://www.idontknow.com/areyousure?answer=yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$result = substr($input, 6, strlen($input) - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
$str = 'href="http://www.idontknow.com/areyousure?answer=yes"';
$string = preg_replace ( '/href="(.*)"/', '\1', $str );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = preg_replace('/href=/i', '', $str);
```