# how to get some part string value from variable

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

i have this in my Controller

```
'thumbnail' => $request->thumbnail
```

inside $request->thumbnail has a record

```
http://localhost/storage/photos/1/image_name.jpg
```

how do i get part of the $request->thumbnail  like "storage/photos/1/image_name.jpg" or just "image_name.jpg"

Thank you for your help,
Best Regards

Comment: First you have a quick look at the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) for a useful function

Comment: I recommend you take a look at [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get part of string using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814930/get-part-of-string-using-php)

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir ok got it thx

Comment: @casenonsensitive already got it thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you operate on urls it would be best to use functions build exactly for this purpose.

`parse_url` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function can be used to split url to different components.

To get the file name from path `basename` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function can be used.

```
<?php

$request = new stdClass();
$request->thumbnail = 'http://localhost/storage/photos/1/image_name.jpg';

$parsedUrl = parse_url($request->thumbnail);

var_dump($parsedUrl);

var_dump($parsedUrl['path']); // "/storage/photos/1/image_name.jpg"

var_dump(basename($parsedUrl['path'])); // "image_name.jpg"
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["path"]=>
  string(32) "/storage/photos/1/image_name.jpg"
}
string(32) "/storage/photos/1/image_name.jpg"
string(14) "image_name.jpg"
```